# How to run tests by directory using the JUnit5 console launcher

Tags: junit5

I'm trying to run tests using the `--select-directory` option in `junit-platform-console-standalone` but tests aren't being discovered. The docs don't have examples for this so I'm a bit lost.

My project looks like this

```
/home/me/
  source/com/mypackage/MyClass.java
  unit-tests/com/mypackage/MyClassTest.java
  integ-tests/com/mypackage/MyClassIntegTest.java
  eclipse-bin/com/mypackage/
    MyClass.class
    MyClassTest.class
    MyClassIntegTest.class
```

I can run tests with `java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone.jar -cp $JUNIT_CLASS_PATH -c com.mypackage.MyClassTest` succesfully.

I'm trying to run just the tests under `unit-tests` only. So far I've tried:

- `java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone.jar -cp $JUNIT_CLASS_PATH -d /home/me/unit-tests`
- `java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone.jar -cp $JUNIT_CLASS_PATH -d /home/me/eclipse-bin`

I even tried to discover them by file

- `java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone.jar -cp $JUNIT_CLASS_PATH -f /home/me/eclipse-bin/com/mypackage/MyClassTest.class`
- `java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone.jar -cp $JUNIT_CLASS_PATH -f file:///home/me/eclipse-bin/com/mypackage/MyClassTest.class`

But none of those discover any tests. How are we supposed to use the `-d` and `-f` switches?

Comment: JUnit Jupiter does not support selection of files or directories. It only supports selection of packages, classes, and methods. See the answer from @Sormuras for details on how to scan the classpath.

Comment: If selecting using directories wasn't supported, then why would the "--select-directory" option exist (as an alternative to -p/-c etc)? I have the same question - how do we make --select-directory work? (I don't want to use the --scan-classpath workaround as when classpath has lots of dependencies that's much more work (hence slower) than needed. And anyway it doesn't answer the original question which is how does  "--select-directory" work). Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone.jar --class-path unit-tests:eclipse-bin --scan-class-path
```

after getting rid of all `*Test.class` files under `eclipse-bin/`.